# Wildcard in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, wildcard

Is it possible to use a kind of wildcards to find and replace strings in Notepad++?

Let's say I have below file:

```
 <Check id="2">text<Condition>foo<Field condition="" field="boo"/>
 <Value>20971520</Value>
 <Check id="14">text<Condition>foo<Field condition="" field="boo"/>
 <Value>5151520</Value>
```

What I need is to remove all the fields that look like:

```
<Check id="2">text<Condition>foo<Field condition="" field="boo"/>
```

Where the id="2" is a variable, and keep the `<Value>5151520</Value>` so the desired output would be:

```
 <Value>20971520</Value>
 <Value>5151520</Value>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the value in `id` always a number? Is the rest of the line always the same exact value except for the id? Please be more specific about the content.

Comment: @KenWhite Actually I am trying to be specific as much as possible, the id always a number.

Comment: Well, you answered 1/2 of the questions I asked. Care to try the other half? This site is for **specific** questions, and a vague description of the data and two sample values is not specific. If I didn't feel more information was necessary, I would not have asked you to provide it. I can gladly offer you a solution that will work only with the exact file you provided, but I doubt that's what you're looking for, so provide **specifics** about the data that can be used to write a more general solution that will help you.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry for the missed information, the rest of the line always the same ... sorry once again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use regular expressions in find and replace. Here is a sample that will do what you want. Make sure you have `Search Mode` set to `Regular Expression`.

Find what: `<Check id[^\n]+\n`

Replace with:

That is, leave the Replace with box blank.